# How to extract data from this dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to extract some data from this data frame.

But I don't know how to do this

this is the code of the data frame that I called *Time*

```
   Time = structure(list(NA. = structure(11180, class = "Date"), V2 = structure(11463, class = "Date"), 
    V3 = structure(11744, class = "Date"), V4 = structure(12024, class = "Date"), 
    V5 = structure(12305, class = "Date"), V6 = structure(12585, class = "Date"), 
    V7 = structure(12865, class = "Date"), V8 = structure(13145, class = "Date"), 
    V9 = structure(13425, class = "Date"), V10 = structure(13705, class = "Date"), 
    V11 = structure(13985, class = "Date"), V12 = structure(14265, class = "Date"), 
    V13 = structure(14545, class = "Date"), V14 = structure(14825, class = "Date"), 
    V15 = structure(15105, class = "Date"), V16 = structure(15385, class = "Date"), 
    V17 = structure(15665, class = "Date"), V18 = structure(15945, class = "Date"), 
    V19 = structure(16225, class = "Date"), V20 = structure(16505, class = "Date"), 
    V21 = structure(16785, class = "Date"), V22 = structure(17065, class = "Date"), 
    V23 = structure(17345, class = "Date"), V24 = structure(17625, class = "Date"), 
    V25 = structure(17905, class = "Date"), V26 = structure(18185, class = "Date"), 
    V27 = structure(NA_real_, class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to extract from this dataset all the time datas, and store it in a vector.
If i try to extract

this way stores numbers that are not as.Data type.
like this

```
temp = NA

for(i in 1:n) {
  temp = c(temp,as.Date(Time[1,i]))
}
```

the only way that is working is extracting all of these individually..

```
t1 = Time[1,1]
t2 = Time[1,2]
.
.
.
.
temp1 = c(t1,t2,t3,...,t27)
```

I would like to have elements like *t1* and *t2* preserving the as.Data type.

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the data frame code to work fine. I think that you can accomplish this simply without a loop at all:

```
t= as.Date(t(Time[1,]))
```

This takes the first row, of the dataframe, transposes it with `t()` then reasserts the date with `as.Date()` and drops it into a vector of dates which you can verify with `class()`

```
> class(t)
[1] "Date"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell R what `temp` is supposed to be. It is supposed to be a time object. Declare it as such by assigning it from the first element in your data frame. Now you can append all the other values to it easily with your loop. Or do it without a loop at all, like @sconfluentus shows.

```r
temp <- Time[1, 1]
for(i in 2:ncol(Time)) temp <- c(temp,as.Date(Time[1, i]))
```

Now:

```
print(temp)
# [1] "2000-08-11" "2001-05-21" "2002-02-26" "2002-12-03" "2003-09-10" "2004-06-16" "2005-03-23"
# [8] "2005-12-28" "2006-10-04" "2007-07-11" "2008-04-16" "2009-01-21" "2009-10-28" "2010-08-04"
# [15] "2011-05-11" "2012-02-15" "2012-11-21" "2013-08-28" "2014-06-04" "2015-03-11" "2015-12-16"
# [22] "2016-09-21" "2017-06-28" "2018-04-04" "2019-01-09" "2019-10-16" NA
```